# VSFTPD: Cannot figure this thing out

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp

Alright, I've been giving this the best that I can, reading through various tutorials on google, but I cannot seem to get vsftpd running the way I want. For a short while I had it working with one account, but then that stopped and I haven't been able to get it to work since. I've since reformated and reinstall Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. I used `apt-get install vsftpd` and that's where I am now... I'd really appreciate if anyone could help me understand exactly how this is supposed to work... How do I add FTP accounts and set their home directory to something like `/var/www/public_html`?

Comment: Not programming.

Answer (score 1):

There is an online copy of the vsftpd.conf man page available [here](http://vsftpd.beasts.org/vsftpd_conf.html).  I would recommend reading through all the configuration options available and determine how you want your ftp server to function as there are a TON of available options...

As for creating users, unless it's configured for anonymous access, vsftpd will authenticate any local user.  You can use PAM to control who has rights to login to the FTP daemon also.  These settings should also provide you with a starting point for locking a user to a specific directory:

- chroot_local_user
- chroot_list_enable
- secure_chroot_dir
- local_root

That should get you started...

Answer (score 0):

If not the tutorials, I guess your best bet is `man vsftpd` and `man 5 vsftpd.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

The best few lines when dealing with VSFTP

```
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
```

Getting the directory structure your after ... look at chroot settings.